# MongoDB v3.2 compiled binaries are over 500 MB

Tags: mongodb, compilation, scons

I just compiled `MongoDB v3.2` by using a very standard flags to `scons`, as it is documented in their [wiki](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source):

```
scons core --ssl --disable-warnings-as-errors
scons install --prefix /usr/local --disable-warnings-as-errors
```

That worked, but binaries are rather large, 200~500 MB each:

```
# for x in mongo*; do file $x; du -sh $x; done
mongo: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=69333c37057636d730d21940550f6ecc45f7474b, not stripped
196M    mongo
mongod: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=1d1b8122b74729d042fee025a1bdb2999fe99fcc, not stripped
521M    mongod
mongoperf: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=5bfb47e755271efbdbed1de5b8130a41da5d026e, not stripped
511M    mongoperf
mongos: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=6409c6eb3d4f771fd9e41fbc87985384cc7b5453, not stripped
254M    mongos
```

This seems weird... like I've forgotten some compression flag or similar. I believe it has something to do with the `not stripped` in the `file` command output. How can I tell `scons` to strip/compress it?

Comment: Just run `strip mongod`, and also `man strip` for details. :-)

Comment: Thank you Sir, that worked very well :)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, as mentioned in the comments, `strip` from *GNU Development Tools* is the answer:

```
# for x in mongo*; do strip -s $x; file $x; du -sh $x; done                                                               
mongo: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=69333c37057636d730d21940550f6ecc45f7474b, stripped
16M     mongo
mongod: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=1d1b8122b74729d042fee025a1bdb2999fe99fcc, stripped
30M     mongod
mongoperf: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=5bfb47e755271efbdbed1de5b8130a41da5d026e, stripped
30M     mongoperf
mongos: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=6409c6eb3d4f771fd9e41fbc87985384cc7b5453, stripped
14M     mongos
```